# Azure Devops Dashboards - How to chart the trend of query results over time based on work item history?

Tags: azure-devops, powerbi

I want to be able to generate a stacked bar chart based on the results of a query, for example the number of open bugs and open features. I would like to see the resulting number of open bugs vs features from that query over a time period, for example the last 30 days. Specifically the number of bugs vs features that were open on that particular day, regardless of their current status. Is there a way to do this using an existing out of the box widget? I believe it should be possible to figure out this information using the history. Alternatively, is it possible to simply store the totals from the query somewhere in devops and then chart it? Or would I need to write a script to export the query results via the api and then use something like the power bi widget to chart it?

Answer (score 0):

Sure, you can set up a chart of the query about the bugs and features opened in the last 30 days.

To meet this demand, you can do like as the steps below:

1. Set up a query with the following filter clauses. Save this query to the **Shared Queries** folder.

   **`Work Item Type`** **`In`** **`Bug,Feature`**

   **`State`** **`=`** **`[Any]`**

   **`Created Date`** **`>=`** **`@StartOfDay('-30d')`**

   [image]
2. On the **Charts** tab of the new query, create a new chart for the query like as below.

   [image]
3. After saving the chart, add this chart to a specified dashboard in the project.

   [image]
4. After above steps, navigate to the specified dashboard in the project, you can see the chart on the dashboard.

   [image]

**[UPDATE]**

According to your latest reply, you want to get the Bug and Feature that were open state in the last 30 days. For these work items, we can think they satisfy one of the following conditions:

- The work items were closed in the last 30 days, no matter what date they were created.
- The work items are still open state currently. They do not have the closed date yet.

So, set up the query like as below should be able to match these work items.

**`Work Item Type`** **`In`** **`Bug,Feature`**

**`And`** **`State`** **`=`** **`[Any]`**

**`And`** **`Closed Date`** **`>=`** **`@StartOfDay('-30d')`**

**`Or`** **`Closed Date`** **`=`**

Group the last two clauses.

[image]

Then create the chart for the query.

Comment: Sorry, but this doesnt quite answer my question. I know how to create a chart, my question is asking if there's a way to get how many bugs were in an open state at say the start of day for each of the last 30 days. The create date isnt relevant because a bug created 2 months ago could still currently be open.

Comment: Hi @ThomasKelly, I have updated my answer with more suggestions for your demands. Please check it.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe the stacked chart would go some way to answering your problem.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/report/dashboards/charts?toc=%2Fazure%2Fdevops%2Fboards%2Ftoc.json&bc=%2Fazure%2Fdevops%2Fboards%2Fbreadcrumb%2Ftoc.json&view=azure-devops#add-a-trend-chart

That produces charts with date as the x axis which, I think, is what you're looking for.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).